# how to add h1 in logo wordpress only in header

Tags: php, html, wordpress, css

My site is : [Design Spicy](http://designspicy.com/) it's on wordpress

I want to place h1 in home page logo only if post page regular logo i uses image logo how can i put the h1 text 
i tired that but not working fine i want seo optimize h1 in logo

```
<?php
    if ( is_front_page()) 
    { ?>
        <h1>
            <a href="http://designspicy.com/">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/image/logo.png" alt="" title="Design Spicy">
            </a>
           Design Spicy
        </h1>
<?php 
    } 
    else 
    { ?>
        <a href="http://designspicy.com/">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/image/logo.png" alt="" title="Design Spicy">
        </a>
<?php 
    } 
?>
```

any way to do this ? without change design ?

Comment: So you only want the h1 to show on the homepage?

Comment: if logo from home page than add h1 else simple logo without h1

Comment: Your code should work. What happens on the homepage with that code?

Comment: but i want to hide h1 from logo

Comment: with seo rules without broke any seo terms

Comment: Just move the logo above the h1 tag?

Comment: show h1 in home page only and hide h1 in other page
and add h1 in logo this is my question ?

Comment: That is what your code is doing. It will only show the h1 text on the homepage...

Comment: try to understand if i show my site name on logo and also h1 :( 
how look like the output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the code i sure it's work :)

```
<?php
if (is_home() || is_front_page())
{ ?>
   <h1 style="font-size:0px">Design Spicy</h1>
   <a href="http://designspicy.com/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/image/logo.png" alt="" title="Design Spicy"></a>

<?php 
} 
else 
{ ?>
    <a href="http://designspicy.com/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/image/logo.png" alt="" title="Design Spicy"></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this error correction   
 <?php
    if ( is_home()) 
    { ?>
       <h1>
       <a href="http://designspicy.com/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/image/logo.png" alt="" title="Design Spicy"></a></h1>
       <h1>Design Spicy</h1>
    <?php 
    } 
    else 
    { ?>
        <a href="http://designspicy.com/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/image/logo.png" alt="" title="Design Spicy"></a>
    <?php } ?>
```

and also :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('h1:nth-child(2)').css('font-size', 0);
 });
```

Comment: if i use above code i show the text beside the logo :(

Comment: yes, its possible. in jquery you can make design spicy font-size to zero

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add something only on homepage you must use

```
if (is_home() || is_front_page())
```

instead of

```
if ( is_front_page())
```

using jquery you can do this

here is your html

```
<h1>
    <a href="http://designspicy.com/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/image/logo.png" alt="" title="Design Spicy"></a>Design Spicy</h1>
```

and then use jquery

```
$(function(){
   text = $('h1').css('font-size', 0);
 });
```

Comment: i dont have if else problem brother but seo and css question

Comment: your logic is nice but if not home page than ? my all the page's h1 font style=0  ??

Comment: I gave you Idea , you can add a class to this h1 and apply the jquery to that class